# increase in the size of database server log file

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, logfile

I have been facing an issue with the Microsoft SQL Server logs. The environment consists of two servers, one is SharePoint, and the other is SQL server. There is only one web application in SharePoint that I am using. The size of the SharePoint_Config database log file has increased to 120 GB. Also, the MDF file size was not that big.
There is not too much data in the SharePoint application.

Did anybody face this kind of issue before? If so what was the reason or cause of the increasing size of the log file?

What has been done to solve the issue?

Comment: When was the last time you did a transaction log backup? If you aren't doing them, why are you using the Full Recovery Model? (Or at least, I suspect you are.)

Comment: Could you please check the recovery mode for this database? Here is an explanation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Look at the recovery type of your database - it is probably FULL or BULK LOGGED which means that unless you schedule transaction log backups, your transaction log cannot reuse the old VLFs.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the feedback, I just would like to mention that I actually have three environments, one development environment which contains one SharePoint server and one SQL server, second staging environment which contains one SharePoint server and one SQL server, third production environment which contains two frontend server and two application and two clustered SQL server.